# Why getTrace() Won't work for public method in OOP php

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a custom debugger using the code shown below and it works fine for protected and private methods but won't work for public method. Can you help please?

```
class newTrace{

public $showTrace = false; 

function GetCallingMethodName(){
    if($this->showTrace){
        $e = new Exception();
        $traceArr = $e->getTrace(); 
        $trace = $traceArr[2]; 
        $traceMsg = $trace['class'] .'::'. $trace['function'] .' args:'. json_encode($trace['args']) .' in '. str_replace("\\", "/", $trace['file']) .' ['. $trace['line'] .']'; 
        echo "<script>console.log('". $traceMsg ."')</script>"; 
    }
}
function logMsg($msg){ 
    if($this->showTrace){
        echo '<script>console.log("'. $msg .'")</script>'; 
    }
}

function showTrace(){
    $this->showTrace = true;
}

private function methodOne($arg1, $arg2){

    echo 'in methodOne<br>';
    $this->logMsg('this is a sample message'); 
}
public function methodTwo($arg){ 
    echo 'in methodTwo<br>';
}
protected function methodThree(){ 
    echo 'in methodThree<br>';
}
public function __call($method, $arguments) {
    if(method_exists($this, $method)) {
        $this->GetCallingMethodName();
        return call_user_func_array(array($this,$method),$arguments);
    }
}
} 


$a = new newTrace;
$a->showTrace();
$a->methodOne('arg1', ['arg2']);
$a->methodTwo(12);
$a->methodThree();
```

Here is an example output:

[image: http://screencast.com/t/LPFgbFN2eY0]

Comment: Your code snippet appears to link to your screenshot too. Please post the code here anyway.

Comment: Oops sorry for the misplaced link, I've added the code snippet here plz take a look @rjdown